# SonarQube - How LOC is calculated

Tags: sonarqube, project, licensing, lines-of-code

I am using SonarQube Developer Edition 5.6.7 (LTS) and have bought a license supporting 5 million LOC. We are using RBAC and SonarQube runner by having a project key and templates.

I would like to know:

a. How are is the LOC usage calculated - suppose if I have a project which is scanned twice using different project keys -- will this cause duplicity? What should be the best way to scan the same project at different

b. I wish to analyze the same project using Manual and then as part of a CI cycle -- How can I publish two different reports without consuming extra LOC?

c. Using the multibranch plugin allows me to scan and share results in the same project. However, how can I get the results via an API so that if I wish to publish the results to a dashboard reporting tool branch wise -- I can use that API.

Answer (score 1):

Answer a:

> LOCs are computed by summing up the LOCs of each project analyzed. The
>   LOCs used for a project are the LOCs found during the most recent
>   analysis of this project.

Source: https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/

Answer b: Publishing them in the same project with the same key won't consume extra LOC.

Answer c: I don't know this plugin, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for reply, we are already using the same project key and branch properties too. But we are not able to get the reports from each branch using API. Thanks anyways.